# Receive error when trying to connect to mongo from iReport 4.5.1

Tags: mongodb, ireport, designer, master-slave

I am trying to create a report using the mongo connector on iReport designer 4.5.1 (jasper). when i create the connection and test it, it says Test successful and gives me the database that i connected to in mongo. 
The issue happens when i try to use the connection in the Report Query in iReport and try to just read the fields before i do anything more complicated. It gives me the following message, 
"Error: not talking to master and retries used up". 
When i connect directly to the server i am able to connect and query and part of the reason might be that i do rs.slaveOk() to get data from slave nodes, my question is if i am connecting to mongo via the iReport where can i issue this command or pass it in as a parameter.
I have reviewed the documentation in the following link but was not able to find anything in regards to the same:
http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Bigdatareportingfornosqlandhadoop/MongoDB

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add ?slaveOk=true or any of the other [MongoDB connection string options](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections) to the connection URI in iReport, eg:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/test?slaveOk=true
```

Comment: You may also want to update to latest iReport (currently 4.6.0).  The screenshot on the [JasperForge link](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Bigdatareportingfornosqlandhadoop/MongoDB) looks different from the current MongoDB connection setup, which includes auth support (user + password).

Comment: Thanks Stennie, other way that worked for me was listing all the servers comma separated and indicating the database name on the final hostname.. mongodb://server1:27017, server2:27017, server3:27017/db